# Error INSERTING Array With Form Validation

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I have three queries about form validation for a tag system using mysqli.
.what is the best practice to escape $tag_no array.
.When $tag_no array is passed from the form integers are passed as strings, so is_int will not work with $tnumber, any ideas?
.Is this the overall best practice for validating an array of tags passed from a form.

Hope this is clear and concise, any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
$tag_no = $_GET['tno'];
$tno = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $tag_no);

if ($tag_no != false) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO `uc` (`UNO`, `BNO`) VALUES ('$uno', '$box');";
   foreach ($tag_no as $tnumber) {
      if (is_int($tnumber)) {
         $query .= "
         INSERT INTO `ut` (`UNO`, `TNO`) VALUES ('$uno', '$tnumber')";
      } else {
         $query .= "INSERT INTO tags (TName) VALUES ('$tagname')"; 
      }
   };
};
mysqli_multi_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: Even local syntax highlighter tells you about missing quotes. Is it *real* code you posted?

Comment: Why don't you pass them as integers instead of strings if that's what you want to do?

Comment: use [ctype_digit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you use [`mysql_multi_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) you'll have to use the ';' to separate the indivdual queries.

So change your code to:

```
foreach ($tag_no as $tnumber) {
    if (is_int($tnumber)) {
        $query .= "
        INSERT INTO `ut` (`UNO`, `TNO`) VALUES ('$uno', '$tnumber');"; # <-- note the ;
    } else {
         $query .= "INSERT INTO tags (TName) VALUES ('$tagname');"; # <-- note the ;
    }
 }
```

Also I'm pretty sure, that this will fail:

```
 foreach ($tag_no as $tnumber)
```

as `$tag_no` is actually a string and foreach expects an array. (You've used it with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.)

Comment: the type of $tnumber is not integer because its sent from from

Comment: Thanks, hek, is_array($tag_no) returns 'array', is there something i am missing?

Comment: `is_array($tag_no);` will never return `'array'`. It will return `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Comment: Sorry, it returns 'TRUE',  i did not mean array literally.

Comment: Than note that you cannot pass an array to `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. You will have to fix this first